# why did nginx setup always redirect to port 8888

Tags: redirect, nginx, port, listen

I've setup a fresh nginx server on my Mac OSX, the default setting listens to the port 8080 and it is for the first time I run nginx, but later on when I do anything to /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf, the browser keeps redirecting localhost:8080 to localhost:8888 no matter what,

What I've tried so far:

nginx -s stop & nginx

brew uninstall nginx --force

brew install nginx

killall nginx

cleanup browser cache

None of which worked.... any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf change the listen directive in server block to

```
    listen       8000;
```

Then, reload configuration...

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Browse to http://localhost:8000. This should fix it for you.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't solve my case... I wind up just using 8888 as my nginx listening port